# Array of objects: Count occurrences of a unique property in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

Given a sample JSON array of objects, like this....

```
[
  {
    "firstName": "Bob",
    "lastName": "Smith",
    "city": "Preston",
    "st": "Florida",
    "age": 15
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Tom",
    "lastName": "Jones",
    "city": "Springfield",
    "st": "Illinois",
    "age": 34
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Mary",
    "lastName": "Hart",
    "city": "Miami",
    "st": "Florida",
    "age": 22
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Jenny",
    "lastName": "Dixon",
    "city": "Palm City",
    "st": "Florida",
    "age": 26
  }
]
```

What is the best way to get the number of occurrences based on the groupings of a particular property? So, let's say I want to produce a JSON object that has each unique state ("st") and the number of occurrences....

```
[
  {
    "st": "Illinois",
    "count": 1
  },
  {
    "st": "Florida",
    "count": 3
  }
]
```

I can do it manually using a for-let, looping through the array, tracking the values as I loop, etc. But I'm sure there's a more efficient way using ES6. Can you please help me out? Thanks.

Comment: `Object.entries(data.reduce((o, d) => ({...o, [d.st]: (o[d.st] || 0) + 1 }), {})).map(([st,count]) => ({ st, count }))`

Comment: `const results = Object.values(data.reduce((obj, item) => {
      obj[item.st] = obj[item.st] = { st: item.st : count: 0 };
      obj[item.st].count++;
      return obj
    }, {}));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to keep a tally

```
let counts = json.reduce((b, a) => {
  let index = b.findIndex(j => j.st === a.st);
  if (index > -1) b[index].count++;
  else b.push({st: a.st, count: 1});
  return b;
}, [])
```

#UPDATE: As mentioned by @epascarello, there is a more efficient way to go about this, removing the `findIndex` loop and using `Object.values`

```
const results = Object.values(json.reduce((obj, item) => {
   obj[item.st] = obj[item.st] || { st: item.st, count: 0 };
   obj[item.st].count++;       
   return obj;}, {}))
```

```js
let json = [{
    "firstName": "Bob",
    "lastName": "Smith",
    "city": "Preston",
    "st": "Florida",
    "age": 15
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Tom",
    "lastName": "Jones",
    "city": "Springfield",
    "st": "Illinois",
    "age": 34
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Mary",
    "lastName": "Hart",
    "city": "Miami",
    "st": "Florida",
    "age": 22
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Jenny",
    "lastName": "Dixon",
    "city": "Palm City",
    "st": "Florida",
    "age": 26
  }
]

let counts = json.reduce((b, a) => {
  let index = b.findIndex(j => j.st === a.st);
  if (index > -1) b[index].count++;
  else b.push({st: a.st, count: 1});
  return b;
}, [])

console.log(counts)

const results = Object.values(json.reduce((obj, item) => {
obj[item.st] = obj[item.st] || { st: item.st, count: 0 };
obj[item.st].count++;       
return obj;}, {}))

console.log(results)
```

Comment: little inefficient using findIndex

Comment: `const results = Object.values(data.reduce((obj, item) => {
      obj[item.st] = obj[item.st] = { st: item.st : count: 0 };
      obj[item.st].count++;
      return obj
    }, {}));`

would be a better way so you are not constantly looping over the array to find the index

Comment: Thanks @epascarello - a tiny mod to your code and I added it to the answer. Cheers!